# Understanding NP.Reshape with image vectors

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have an RGB image vector in the form of an np.array with shape (1000,48). This is a flattened representation of 1000 distinct 4x4 images in the values RGB respectively. For example images[0] corresponds to 1 image and the first 16 values represent the values for "Red" in each of pixels.

I want to turn this into an np array of shape (1000,4,4,3) - where each index refers to a 3d matrix encoding each image.

So far I have done the following functions

```
###option 1
data = images.reshape(1000,4,4,3)

##option 2
red = images[:,:16].reshape(1000,4,4,1)
green = images[:,16:32].reshape(1000,4,4,1)
blue = images[:,32:].reshape(1000,4,4,1)
data = np.concatenate((red,green,blue), axis=3)
```

When I print the first couple of values under both of these methods, they differ and neither seem to produce a result consistent with the base image. What is the correct way to quickly reshape this dataset?

Comment: Focus for the moment on just one image, `anImage=images[0]`, with shape (48,).  Reshaping that to (4,4,3) assumes that the 1st 3 values the colors for pixel (0,0), etc.  Reshaping to (3,16) or (3,4,4) is more like your 2nd grouping.  We don't have you date so can't say which is correct.

Comment: `reshape` does not change the order of elements in the underlying 1d data buffer,  It just changes how they viewed multidimensionally.

Comment: @hpaulji Okay I so if anImage[0], anImage[16] and anImage[32] all correspond to pixel (0,0) the correct reshape operation is (3,4,4) which should then be transposed?

Comment: Yes.  use `transpose(0,2,3,1)` to preserve the the pixel order.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. Is there a way apply this with an array of images, without iterating through each one?

Comment: That transpose with 4 numbers is for the full 4d images array (1000,3,4,4).  It moves the size 3 dimension from 1 to the end.  I just suggested a focus on one image to make it easier to visualize the layout.

Comment: I was asking about the reshape prior to the transpose - does np.reshape(1000,3,4,4) turn each individual row into the initial grouping?

Comment: Yes, that reshape preserves the order in each inner most size 48 block..  So if `images[0].reshape(3,4,4)` does the right thing, then `images.reshape(1000,3,4,4)` will too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @hpaulji - moving here for visibility

Focus for the moment on just one image, anImage=images[0], with shape (48,). Reshaping that to (4,4,3) assumes that the 1st 3 values the colors for pixel (0,0), etc. Reshaping to (3,16) or (3,4,4) is more like your 2nd grouping. We don't have you date so can't say which is correct.

So if images[0].reshape(3,4,4) does the right thing, then images.reshape(1000,3,4,4) will too